# jQuery included, but jQuery-code is not executed

Tags: jquery, wordpress

jQuery is included in the file, like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
```

And I have a jQuery file that looks like this:

```
$(function() {
alert("j");

$('.event-wrapper a').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next().hide();
    } else {
        $('.event-info').hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    }
});

$('.event-info').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

});

This is not working. I have tried putting only the alert("j"); in the file, and that works so the file is correctly included. How can I fix this?

Comment: check in `$(document).ready(function(){alert("hello")})`

Comment: try check javascript error using firebug on FF

Comment: check @loQ answer, most probably `event` is undefined in your click handler...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress automatically calls jQuery with jQuery.noConflict which means that $ is removed to avoid namespace collisions. When using jQuery with Wordpress you should always use jQuery instead of $.

For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

});
```

In order to get $ back you can use the shortcut described here (and in other answers): http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but your jQuery main function should start like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //your jquery code should go here
        });
```

If you are trying to create a jquery function which you can call on an html element, it should be declared like this:

```
        (function ($) {
            $.fn.myFunc = function (options) {

             //Your code goes here
            }
        })(jQuery);
```

And would be called from an object directly in javascript:

```
        $('#SomeHtmlElementID').myFunc(myArgs);
```

Also, your alert will work regardless of if use jQuery or not, because it is a javascript function, not a function that is exclusive to jQuery.

Comment: `$(function(){ code });` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){ code });` http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Because of reasons specified by @Calle, this should work for you, so that jQuery is passed in as `$` and following use should work as normal.

```
(function($){ $(function(){
   // Your code here...
}) })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Here you can use $ as normal
});
```